# JavaScript Prototype

Tags: javascript, объекты, prototype

```
Array.prototype.summ = function() {
    var summ = 0;
    for(var i in this) {
        summ += this[i];
    }
    return summ;
};

console.log([27,3,10,11,9,85,15].summ());
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему в консоли выводится сумма объекта и сама функция? Почему не без функции?

```
# Console

160function () {
    var summ = 0;
    for(var i in this) {
        summ += this[i];
    }
    return summ;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перебирайте свойства кроме унаследованных в объекте http://javascript.ru/for..in

```js
Array.prototype.summ = function() {
    var summ = 0;
    for(var i in this) {
        if (!this.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
       summ += this[i];
    }
    return summ;
};

console.log([27,3,10,11,9,85,15].summ());
```

**UPD**

Возможно, даже стоит добавить проверку `typeof this[i] == 'number'`, чтобы суммировались только числа.

Comment: благодарю за информацию