# цикл вдруг начал возвращать непонятные вещи

Tags: javascript

есть json база, я бегу по ее элементам за 2 цикла и получаю значения. Я сократил названия переменных для примера. Всё работало еще вчера, не пойму что случилось, но сегодня в my_val стали наряду с индексом массива типа 0,1,2... возвращаться $family, $constructor, each, clone, clean, invoke, associate. Что это? Откуда?

```
for (var aaa in json){
            for (var my_val in json[aaa]['elem_name']){
                alert(my_val);
```

извиняюсь за ссылки, но вот тут оно работает (какая то левая скопированная страница, куда я просто воткнул для теста скрипт): http://shin0by.com/tests/

А вот тут выдает ошибку http://shin0by.com/publications-ru/42-star-citizen-database

Я намеренно добавил алерт для первого прохода в цикле, что бы и там и там было видно что второй цикл возвращает.

В какую сторону сомотреть?

Comment: Дубликат вопроса http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459836/javascript-prototype P.S. У кого голоса остались инициализируйте закрытие как дубликат.

Comment: не пойму я сам могу закрыть вопрос?

Comment: Можете и сами закрыть или удалить, если то решение вам подошло.

Comment: Я все же уточню, в моем случае это будет строка : if (!json[aaa]['elem_name'].hasOwnProperty(my_val)){continue;} ? Оно вроде как заработало, но вдруг это неверное применение, и оно еще выйдет мне боком. Или надо к корню json применять не указывая его ключи?

Comment: так и будет, но еще проверку для внешнего цикла не помешает сделать. У вас же два цикла через `for`.

Comment: Да, само собой. Спасибо!